# CGAL slicer doesn't output polylines in proper order

Tags: cgal

Are there any options or requirements which make
`CGAL::Polygon_mesh_slicer` output to be in correct order.

eg. I've loaded a mesh and converted it to `CGAL::Surface_mesh`. Then I've used slicer on that mesh to get list of polylines. Problem is that these polylines are not in any order CW or CCW.

To be more precise, output polylines are not consecutive

Here is a slice of a cube from the top.

```
o---1--o
|      |
2      3
|      |
o--4---o
```

I would expect that output will be like: 1->2->4->3 or reverse
But I got more or less 1->4->2->3

Answer (score 0):

As stated [here](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polygon_mesh_processing/classCGAL_1_1Polygon__mesh__slicer.html#a2ccb40298bed1b68ffdad07c43f3c04e), "Each resulting polyline P is oriented such that for two consecutive points p and q in P, the normal vector of the face(s) containing the segment pq, the vector pq, and the orthogonal vector of `plane` is a direct orthogonal basis. The normal vector of each face is chosen to point on the side of the face where its sequence of vertices is seen counterclockwise."

So the orientation of the polylines depends on the orientation of the plane and of the mesh faces.

Comment: thanks for your response. I've corrected description to be more precise. If I understand correctly this documentation says about how direction of single polyline is calculated cw or ccw and it depends on face normal. But thing is that my problem is related to order between all polylines. They are just mixed and I cannot create polygon picking up output from slicer one by one

Comment: Orientation of polylines depends on the orientation of your mesh and on the orientation of the plane. So if you have a consistently oriented mesh (and use a consitent orientation if several planes are used) then all polylines should be oriented "similarly". If not I would say it is a bug.